# ffmpeg export video from png sequence is not correct

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a `PNG` sequence with transparent background.

When I use Adobe Media encoder to export to an `MP4` file, the result is correct.

But when I use `FFmpeg` to export the `MP4` file, this result is very strange.

This is the command I used:

```
ffmpeg -i test/frame_%04d.png -pix_fmt yuv444p -c:v libx264 -y ffmpeg_test.mp4
```

Media Encoder: http://test.rto.im/ffmpeg/media_encoder_test.mp4

FFMPEG: http://test.rto.im/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_test.mp4

All images file: test.rto.im/ffmpeg/test.zip

[test.rto.im/ffmpeg/test/frame_0001.png](http://test.rto.im/ffmpeg/test/frame_0001.png)

[test.rto.im/ffmpeg/test/frame_0002.png](http://test.rto.im/ffmpeg/test/frame_0002.png)

[test.rto.im/ffmpeg/test/frame_0003.png](http://test.rto.im/ffmpeg/test/frame_0003.png)
....

Comment: Your'e rendering the video with `libx264`. Have you tried removing the `-pix_fmt yuv444p -c:v libx264` arguments?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i test/frame_%04d.png -y ffmpeg_test.mp4` I have used this command, but the result is the same, it it not correct.

Comment: please fix the broken links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PNG frames are unmatted. So, you'll have to premultiply them to get the same result.

```
ffmpeg -i frames%d.png -vf premultiply=inplace=1 -pix_fmt yuv444p matted.mp4
```

The `premultiply` filter was added in Dec 2016, so you'll need a recent version.

Comment: I use ubuntu 17.04, It said `No such filter:'premultiply'`
I use scoop in windows and installed ffmpeg, it said `Option 'inplace' not found.` `Error initializing filter 'premultiply' with args 'inplace=1'`

Comment: In windows, after I upgrade ffmpeg to latest version, premultiply is working now.